# How can I use FIND function to search for more than two condition in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel

How can I use FIND function in excel to look for more than 2 condition?

[image]

Currently I extracted like this:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE( LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1&"/", IFERROR( FIND("USD",A1), FIND("CNY",A1) )  )-1),"/",REPT(" ",99) ),99))
```

When I add in the third `FIND("AUD",A1)` it gives me error. Am I suppose to use `FIND`?

Comment: can u say what are the 2 conditions?

Comment: Looking for the currency code. USD, CNY, AUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LOOKUP with an array (it will use the last match if there's more than one item found):

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE( LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1&"/", LOOKUP(1E+100,FIND({"USD","CNY","AUD"},A1))  )-1),"/",REPT(" ",99) ),99))
```

Comment: `1E+100` is a very big number. The `FIND` will return an array of numbers or errors, and `LOOKUP` ignores error values, so it will return the last number less than or equal to the lookup value - so in this case it will return the last number.